# Is Joomla a correct choice for a social medium with rankings of products?

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, module, extensions, tags

I'm thinking about creating a certain website and I'm not sure if Joomla is a tool I could use and would be one of the best choices.

I would like to create something like https://www.imdb.com/ , i.e. a site which would be a ranking of certain products, with tags, ratings, opinions, where it would be possible to display for example top 10 products which were tagged by a certain label, these things. Additionally, I'd like it to be a social medium, where people can talk, ask questions on forum etc.

Is Joomla a correct tool to use in such a case? Or is it not really created to hold such websites? Why is it, why isn't it? Is there a much stronger alternative?

I know this is a forum with questions mainly about administering Joomla, but I didn't find anything against such questions in [tour](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/tour), [good questions](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [bad questions](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). So I hope it goes.

Comment: See https://joomla.stackexchange.com/tour#:~:text=Avoid%20questions,than%20answers. & the Meta link from /help/on-topic: https://joomla.meta.stackexchange.com/q/64/12352 You are effectively asking several questions, many that are opinion-based. Any Joomla advocate will say, "Yes, you can build that on Joomla". Just like any web advocate will say, "Yes, you can build a site like that". And any mobile app advocate will say "Yes, You can build a mobile app like that".  It can all be done.  The question comes down to what are you capable of doing.  I don't think you took the [tour] yet - no badge.

Comment: Asking this question at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com will probably result in less biased answers and provide a wider range of answers

Answer (score 1):

Joomla has at least some of the required functionality such as custom fields and other features can be added using third party extensions.

There is at least one extension in the Joomla Extensions Directory, [SP Movie Database](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/sp-movie-database) to make it easy to create a movie database but it may not have all the features you require (e.g. front end access for website visitors to contribute to content etc).

You may also be able to customise a [directory extension](https://extensions.joomla.org/tags/directory) or possibly a [shopping cart extension](https://extensions.joomla.org/tags/shopping-cart) in catalog mode into a movie database. Shopping carts often have ratings and reviews built in that you can take advantage of.

WordPress and other content management systems may be just as suitable as Joomla.

You should also be able to find specific scripts to set up a movie database website although these may not include all the CMS features you will find in Joomla or WordPress or similar.